# Do the Quarterstaff of Alacrity and the Speed enchantment stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons

> #### Quarterstaff of Alacrity
>
> Both ends of this +5 quarterstaff of speed have equal enhancement and special powers, meaning that it allows an additional attack **with each end** every round.

Does that mean this quarterstaff can grant two additional attacks (instead of one) since the attacker would be able to make one additional attack with each end?

BTW, the speed enchantment says the following:

> Speed: When making a full attack action, the wielder of a speed weapon may make one extra attack with it... (This benefit is not cumulative with similar effects, such as a haste spell.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You can make two additional attacks with the staff

It's right there in the description you cite

> it allows an additional attack with each end every round

It has two ends, it allows an additional attack with each end, ergo, it allows  two additional attacks. It's an epic weapon, after all. This is a specific weapon, and its specific abilities are explicitly given. This is different from a generic weapon with the speed enchantment, even though it is called a "quarterstaff of speed".

If you would enchant a weapon twice with the normal Speed enchantment, you would not get to make two additional attacks. The special ability calls out that it is not cumulative with similar abilities, and nothing could be more similar than the very same ability.

Comment: Hmmm... So it can have two attacks because it is an Epic weapon, and a traditional +5 quarterstaff of speed with the same enhancement and special powers on each end can still only make one additional attack per round in total?

Comment: Yes, if you use a normal "Speed" enhancement to your weapon, I think it would not be cumulative with itself, as it does exclude working cumulatively with similar effects.

Comment: In pre-revision *3E* (which includes the *EL*) the magic weapon special ability *speed* also functioned slightly differently. (CTRL-F *speed* [here](http://www.dragon.ee/30srd/magic_weapons.htm).)

Comment: A quarterstaff is considered a double weapon.  Both ends have to be enchanted separately to get the benefits on both strikes.  But if you enchanted a normal quarterstaff with a speed enchantment twice, once on each end, you would get two extra attacks.

Comment: Not *quite* right, for the reason @Kuro_Neko identifies. You could similarly enchant two daggers with Speed, and dual-wield for two extra attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would get two extra attacks.  But keep in mind that this is subject to the Two Weapon Fighting rules and the penalties therein.  A Quarterstaff is a [double weapon](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Double_Weapon).  You can choose to wield it as a normal two-handed weapon and avoid the TWF penalties, but in that case you would get only one extra attack.